# GWMI - Find out if Domain Controllers are physical or virtual via script

Tags: active-directory, powershell, wmi, powershell-v3.0, wmic

I have tried to create a script for extracting but the output is not quite I desired.

```
$Servers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object Name

foreach($server in $servers)
{
$compsystem = gwmi -q "Select * from win32_computersystem" | Select Model

write-output $Server is $compsystem"
}
```

The output is something like :

@{Name=ServerName} is @{Model=Proliant DL360 G6}

The servername is different but the Model is the same so i think it's in a continous loop after the first servers.

Any ideeas ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You are never using the variable `$server`, so all your output is from the local machine you are running the script on. To run the command on the actual servers you can use [`Invoke-Command`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command):

```
$servers |Foreach-Object {
    $compsystem = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.name -ScriptBlock { gwmi -q "Select * from win32_computersystem" }
    Write-Host ("{0} is {1}" -f $_.Name,$compsystem.Model)
}
```